# Removing data outside country map boundary in R

Tags: r, polygon, sf, ggplot

This is a location point dataset (lat and long) that I want to map, and I want to remove density lines outside the US map borders.

```
df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(44.085655, 45.75582402, 44.465059, 
46.85455171, 44.79125494, 44.085655, 44.43086558, 45.75582402, 
44.77051274, 45.19945455, 47.27561322, 44.21957345, 44.3090238, 
44.94220871, 44.961121, 44.710093, 44.34052462, 45.11789419, 
45.95867596, 46.56683647, 46.50792317, 44.45755466, 45.07106473, 
44.28764499, 45.77015307, 44.71947041, 45.00157585, 44.68872029, 
44.533648, 46.88808589, 44.56185674, 44.08025478, 45.36716924, 
44.82353463, 45.06309272, 46.14316994, 44.47153, 44.29015112, 
44.3461, 44.3429524167217, 44.3622947358144, 46.861376854859, 
46.193502, 44.28649439, 44.677071, 44.656418), Longitude = c(-70.164692, 
-87.08797801, -73.1317265, -68.03996219, -68.80975286, -70.164692, 
-71.18455899, -87.08797801, -85.64676572, -67.27073026, -68.58126288, 
-73.50262934, -71.75870552, -72.17091902, -74.82915083, -73.447775, 
-74.12240542, -87.60659852, -86.22085006, -87.408152, -84.3395823, 
-83.33775439, -83.42056958, -85.39666393, -84.72208165, -84.69989941, 
-84.66704973, -85.64621272, -87.933788, -67.99941449, -70.54746671, 
-70.18023411, -68.53049377, -68.73114004, -69.87230606, -67.83254698, 
-73.20752, -69.69422198, -69.7603999999998, -69.7510695984823, 
-69.8046068622161, -68.0330276970697, -67.801417, -69.6878877839999, 
-67.57706, -67.646081)), row.names = c(NA, -46L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am mapping this data with this code:

```
# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa, fill = "blue",color = "black",alpha=.9) +
  coord_sf(
    xlim = c(-100, -70),
    ylim = c(40, 51),
   default_crs = sf::st_crs(4326),
    crs = st_crs("ESRI:102003"),
    expand = TRUE,
    lims_method = "box",
    label_axes = list(
      bottom = "E", top = "E",
      left = "N", right = "N"
    ))+stat_density2d_filled(data = df1, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill=(..level..),
         alpha = (..level..)),  geom = "polygon")
```

The plot is like this[image]

I am looking to remove the excess data points on the map (Blue texture). I have used this code to remove those but In step 2 I have a problem :

```
#Step 1
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = vetrace1[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], data = vetrace1,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
step 2
df1<- spdf[!is.na(over(spdf, as(usa, "SpatialPolygons"))), ]
# step 3
df1<- as.data.frame(df1)
```

The error I got is :

`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'over': no method or default for coercing “sf” to “SpatialPolygons”`

How can I trim this map?

Comment: Where does `usa` come from? Its not in `sf` or `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to do here would be to use the underlying kernel density estimator and crop that to the USA bounds, and feed that to your map.

This code returns a data frame of smoothed values, and should be using the same bandwidths that `stat_density2d` uses. Here's a working example that starts with your `df1` data frame:

Going to need `sf`, and switch spherical geometry off because its not needed and the `usa` data I've got breaks with it on:

```
library(sf)
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
usa = st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))
```

Now get the default smoothing parameters and smooth. I suppose we could let `kde2d` do this internally but I've done it here to be explicit. Then do the smooth:

```
h <-  c(MASS::bandwidth.nrd(df1$Longitude), MASS::bandwidth.nrd(df1$Latitude))
den = MASS::kde2d(df1$Longitude, df1$Latitude,h=h,n=100)
```

This `den` is a list of x and y vectors plus a z matrix, we want to turn that into a raster so we can work with it in the `terra` package:

```
denxyz = data.frame(expand.grid(x=den$x, y=den$y))
denxyz$density = c(den$z)
```

Now use the `terra` package to mask it to the USA data:

```
library(terra)
rd = rast(denxyz)
crs(rd) = "epsg:4326"
rd = mask(rd, usa)
```

If you do a `plot(rd)` you'll see its masked out as NA outside the US area.

[image]

For plotting, I do hit problems with `ggplot` and `geom_sf` when reprojecting map data like this, so I prefer to use `tmap`:

```
box = st_bbox(c(xmin = -100, xmax = -70, ymax = 51, ymin = 40), crs = st_crs(4326))
library(tmap)
tm_shape(usa, bbox=box, projection = st_crs("ESRI:102003")) + tm_polygons() + tm_shape(rd) +  tm_raster()
```

[image]

and this can be tweaked to look a bit more like your original if you need. For ggplot2 though, I think you have to convert the masked raster back to a list of x, y, filled data and use `geom_raster`, but this gives me stupid error messages if I try. For example this simplified version:

```
> ggplot() + geom_sf(data=usa) + coord_sf(default_crs=st_crs(4326), crs=st_crs("ESRI:102003"), xlim=c(-100,-70), ylim=c(40,51)) + geom_raster(data=denxyz, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=density))
Error in `geom_raster()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `matrix()`:
! vector is too large
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

which I think must be failing because it is trying to reproject the density to a really fine scale and failing badly. But maybe you can find a way to plot this. I'd use `tmap`, which seems to just work nicely with map data.

Also, doing kernel smoothing in lat-long coordinates is generally a bad thing to do since the X and Y coordinates aren't equivalent, especially at these latitudes away from the equator.